# Is there a way to figure out poetry style of text on a text/markdown file?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

There is a markdown/text file that has poetical phrases in between normal paragraphs, like so:

```
Mr. Lewes reaches this conclusion: "If, therefore, we reflect what a poem _Faust_ is, and that it contains almost every variety of style and metre, it will be tolerably evident that no one unacquainted with the original can form an adequate idea of it from translation,"  which is certainly correct of any translation wherein something of the rhythmical variety and beauty of the original is not retained. That very much of the rhythmical character may be retained in English, was long ago shown by Mr. Carlyle,  in the passages which he translated, both literally and rhythmically, from the _Helena_ (Part Second). In fact, we have so many instances of the possibility of reciprocally transferring the finest qualities of English and German poetry, that there is no sufficient excuse for an unmetrical translation of _Faust_. I refer especially to such subtile and melodious lyrics as "The Castle by the Sea," of Uhland, and the "Silent Land" of Salis, translated by Mr. Longfellow; Goethe's "Minstrel" and "Coptic Song," by Dr. Hedge; Heine's "Two Grenadiers," by Dr. Furness and many of Heine's songs by Mr Leland; and also to the German translations of English lyrics, by Freiligrath and Strodtmann. 

> Life of Goethe (Book VI.).

> Mr. Lewes gives the following advice: "The English reader would perhaps best succeed who should first read Dr. Anster's brilliant paraphrase, and then carefully go through Hayward's prose translation." This is singularly at variance with the view he has just expressed. Dr. Anster's version is an almost incredible dilution of the original, written in _other_ metres; while Hayward's entirely omits the element of poetry.

> Foreign Review, 1828.

> When Freiligrath can thus give us Walter Scott:—


"Kommt, wie der Wind kommt,  
Wenn Wälder erzittern  
Kommt, wie die Brandung  
Wenn Flotten zersplittern!  
Schnell heran, schnell herab,  
Schneller kommt Al'e!—  
Häuptling und Bub' und Knapp,  
Herr und Vasalle!"
```

I want to place three ``` above and below all such poetical constructs on the markdown so that the output to HTML has the poetry inside a `<pre>` tag. Like this:

````
```
"Kommt, wie der Wind kommt,  
Wenn Wälder erzittern  
Kommt, wie die Brandung  
Wenn Flotten zersplittern!  
Schnell heran, schnell herab,  
Schneller kommt Al'e!—  
Häuptling und Bub' und Knapp,  
Herr und Vasalle!"  
```
````

Am wondering if there's a regex to match such patterns on a text file reliably?

---

Another situation:

I sometimes have following formatting to identify poetical prose:

```
abra ca dabra op
  lorem ipsum holy this 
line doesn't have 
  an indent but it's in
continuity of the 
  structure that sits together.
```

Comment: on what basis you decide it is `poetical phrases` ? any sort of pattern or rule ?

Comment: Either you'll need a very narrow, simplistic definition of what constitutes "poetical phrases", perhaps based on line length and number of lines separating those lines from other text... or you'll need really good AI!

Comment: Yep, that's driving me crazy. It's that visual formatting on text that I see and just know w/o reading anything, but I don't think we wanna go down the path of prose. Don't wanna get into neural net or a language processing research for this!

Comment: Without proper set of rules and defined structure, you can't write a regex

Comment: Sounds like a complicated pattern matching problem, and computers are not as good at it as people. This problem alone could be a topic of entire PhD in computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, I'd agree with the comments that this problem might be best solved by AI. That being said, you've got an AI in your head (minus the A), and if you can look at a well-formatted document and define patterns of what comprises "poetry", you can write a regex to select it.

---

`^((?:.+\n)+.+)$` This regex selects lines which have only one newline between lines of content. As long as your markdown/text file puts at least two newlines between ordinary paragraphs, and the poems are more than one line long (like in your example), it'll capture them.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/XB3GRa/7/)

---

`^((?:.+\n  .+\n)+)$` If you'd prefer a more strict definition of "poetry", this regex looks for a line of content, followed by an indented line of content below it (also like in your example). The regex won't match "badly formatted" poems that don't end with an indented line.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/XB3GRa/8/)

Comment: I'd argue that our I is not in our head, but rather we are able to connect to UI (Universal Intelligence), kind of Aristotle's way of saying things :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an underlying problem here that is not soluble by AI in that fixing linebreaks is difficult in markdown because of the definition of the markup itself.

In Multimarkdown a double blank at the end of a line is allowed to mean newline not paragraph end.

In Commonmark spec it explicitly says that newline, carriage return, or the two together are equivalent and mean end of paragraph. (This is, of course to accommodate text conventionally marked from (Old) Mac, Unix, or Windows systems so they all import correctly. However it has the side effect of making newline and end para impossible.)

The only route I see is via pre-formatted text, but this generally changes to font to monospaced which is not wanted for verse.

The verse world is no less complicated in the LaTeX world where there are at least three solutions depending which package you use (verse, gmverse, poetry, poemcol).

So I think the spec needs extending: either with an option for preformatted blocks or another mechanism.